# How best use Regular Expressions to convert Heirarchical Text File into XML?

Tags: php, xml, regex, parsing, text

Good morning -

I'm interested in seeing an efficient way of parsing the values of an *heirarchical* text file (i.e., one that has a Title => Multiple Headings => Multiple Subheadings => Multiple Keys => Multiple Values) into a simple XML document. For the sake of simplicity, the answer would be written using:

- Regex (preferrably in PHP)
- or, PHP code (e.g., if looping were more efficient)

Here's an example of an Inventory file I'm working with. Note that Header = **FOODS**, Sub-Header = **Type (A, B...)**, Keys = **PRODUCT (or CODE, etc.)** and Values may have one more more lines.

```
**FOODS - TYPE A**
___________________________________
**PRODUCT**
1) Mi Pueblito Queso Fresco Authentic Mexican Style Fresh Cheese;
2) La Fe String Cheese
**CODE**
Sell by date going back to February 1, 2009
**MANUFACTURER**
Quesos Mi Pueblito, LLC, Passaic, NJ.
**VOLUME OF UNITS**
11,000 boxes
**DISTRIBUTION**
NJ, NY, DE, MD, CT, VA
___________________________________
**PRODUCT**
1) Peanut Brittle No Sugar Added;
2) Peanut Brittle Small Grind;
3) Homestyle Peanut Brittle Nuggets/Coconut Oil Coating
**CODE**
1) Lots 7109 - 8350 inclusive;
2) Lots 8198 - 8330 inclusive;
3) Lots 7075 - 9012 inclusive;
4) Lots 7100 - 8057 inclusive;
5) Lots 7152 - 8364 inclusive
**MANUFACTURER**
Star Kay White, Inc., Congers, NY.
**VOLUME OF UNITS**
5,749 units
**DISTRIBUTION**
NY, NJ, MA, PA, OH, FL, TX, UT, CA, IA, NV, MO and IN
**FOODS - TYPE B**
___________________________________
**PRODUCT**
Cool River Bebidas Naturales - West Indian Cherry Fruit Acerola 16% Juice;
**CODE**
990-10/2 10/5
**MANUFACTURER**
San Mar Manufacturing Corp., Catano, PR.
**VOLUME OF UNITS**
384
**DISTRIBUTION**
PR
```

And here's the desired output (please excuse any XML syntactical errors):

```
<foods>
    <food type = "A" >
        <product>Mi Pueblito Queso Fresco Authentic Mexican Style Fresh Cheese</product>
        <product>La Fe String Cheese</product>
        <code>Sell by date going back to February 1, 2009</code>
        <manufacturer>Quesos Mi Pueblito, LLC, Passaic, NJ.</manufacturer>
        <volume>11,000 boxes</volume>
        <distibution>NJ, NY, DE, MD, CT, VA</distribution>
    </food>
    <food type = "A" >
        <product>Peanut Brittle No Sugar Added</product>
        <product>Peanut Brittle Small Grind</product>
        <product>Homestyle Peanut Brittle Nuggets/Coconut Oil Coating</product>
        <code>Lots 7109 - 8350 inclusive</code>
    <code>Lots 8198 - 8330 inclusive</code>
    <code>Lots 7075 - 9012 inclusive</code>
    <code>Lots 7100 - 8057 inclusive</code>
    <code>Lots 7152 - 8364 inclusive</code>
        <manufacturer>Star Kay White, Inc., Congers, NY.</manufacturer>
        <volume>5,749 units</volume>
        <distibution>NY, NJ, MA, PA, OH, FL, TX, UT, CA, IA, NV, MO and IN</distribution>
    </food>
    <food type = "B" >
        <product>Cool River Bebidas Naturales - West Indian Cherry Fruit Acerola 16% Juice</product>
        <code>990-10/2 10/5</code>
        <manufacturer>San Mar Manufacturing Corp., Catano, PR</manufacturer>
        <volume>384</volume>
        <distibution>PR</distribution>
    </food>
</FOODS>
<!-- and so forth -->
```

So far, my approach (which might be quite inefficient with a huge text file) would be one of the following:

1. **Loops and multiple Select/Case statements**, where the file is loaded into a string buffer, and while looping through each line, see if it matches one of the header/subheader/key lines, append the appropriate xml tag to a xml string variable, and then add the child nodes to the xml based on IF statements regarding which key name is most recent (which seems time-consuming and error-prone, esp. if the text changes even slightly) -- OR
2. **Use REGEX (Regular Expressions)** to find and replace key fields with appropriate xml tags, clean it up with an xml library, and export the xml file. Problem is, I barely use regular expressions, so I'd need some *example-based* help.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "Note that ... may have one more more lines." - can you give an example of that, too?

Comment: To Max S. - I've added my approach to the bottom of the question.

To VolkerK - please see the two examples have multiple values under the **PRODUCT** header, and that the xml example I provided (rightly or wrongly) has more than one <product> item, as needed.

Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, the 1), 2), 3) thingy. What did you mean by "Values" in that sentence? Can _each_ of the 1), 2) lines encompass more than one line? Or would it be feasible to write a rudimentary line-by-line parser?

Comment: The Values in this case are the items under each key, so they may not have a number in front, or, if there are multiple values, there **will** numbers. Meaning, the format isn't a simple as being "newline-delimited" (i.e., KEY\nVALUE\nKEY\VALUE), since some keys might possibly have over 30 values, each on separate lines. I've just give a few short examples for the sake of time.

Comment: Sorry for me being nit-picky (esp. since you already got an answer that shows you how to write a "proper" parser) but as I understand you it really _is_ newline-delimited even though it is "key\nvalue\value\value\nkey\value\nkey\value\nvalue\nvalue". What I mean is: You only have to read one line at a time and can decide on this single line (and maybe one single state) what to do, you don't have to "carry around" partial values over to the next line.

Comment: It's fine. My point was that this process of "load line, **multiple** nested conditions, separate function call to add a node to xml file, loop" is feasible, but is this the **best** or most *efficient* way to do this, vs. running a handful of regex expression to search and replace, and at least get a rough cut of an xml string finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example you can use as a starting point. At least I hope it gives you an idea...

```
<?php
define('TYPE_HEADER', 1);
define('TYPE_KEY', 2);
define('TYPE_DELIMETER', 3);
define('TYPE_VALUE', 4);

$datafile = 'data.txt';
$fp = fopen($datafile, 'rb') or die('!fopen');

// stores (the first) {header} in 'name' and the root simplexmlelement in 'element'
$container = array('name'=>null, 'element'=>null);
// stores the name for each item element, the value for the type attribute for subsequent item elements and the simplexmlelement of the current item element
$item = array('name'=>null, 'type'=>null, 'current_element'=>null);
// the last **key** encountered, used to create new child elements in the current item element when a value is encountered
$key = null;

while ( false!==($t=getstruct($fp)) ) {
  switch( $t[0] ) {
    case TYPE_HEADER:
      if ( is_null($container['element']) ) {
        // this is the first time we hit **header - subheader**
        $container['name'] = $t[1][0];
        // ugly hack, < . name . />
        $container['element'] = new SimpleXMLElement('<'.$container['name'].'/>');
        // each subsequent new item gets the new subheader as type attribute
        $item['type'] = $t[1][1];
        // dummy implementation: "deducting" the item names from header/container[name]
        $item['name'] = substr($t[1][0], 0, -1);
      }
      else {
        // hitting **header - subheader** the (second, third, nth) time 
        /*
        header must be the same as the first time (stored in container['name']).
        Otherwise you need another container element since 
        xml documents can only have one root element
        */
        if ( $container['name'] !== $t[1][0] ) {
          echo $container['name'], "!==",  $t[1][0], "\n";
          die('format error');
        }
        else {
          // subheader may have changed, store it for future item elements
          $item['type'] = $t[1][1];
        }
      }
      break;
    case TYPE_DELIMETER:
      assert( !is_null($container['element']) );
      assert( !is_null($item['name']) );
      assert( !is_null($item['type']) );
      /* that's maybe not a wise choice.
      You might want to check the complete item before appending it to the document.
      But the example is a hack anyway ...so create a new item element and append it to the container right away
      */
      $item['current_element'] = $container['element']->addChild($item['name']);
      // set the type-attribute according to the last **header - subheader** encountered
      $item['current_element']['type'] = $item['type'];
      break;
    case TYPE_KEY:
      $key = $t[1][0];
      break;
    case TYPE_VALUE:
      assert( !is_null($item['current_element']) );
      assert( !is_null($key) );
      // this is a value belonging to the "last" key encountered
      // create a new "key" element with the value as content
      // and addit to the current item element
      $tmp = $item['current_element']->addChild($key, $t[1][0]);
      break;
    default:
      die('unknown token');
  }
}

if ( !is_null($container['element']) ) {
  $doc = dom_import_simplexml($container['element']);
  $doc = $doc->ownerDocument;
  $doc->formatOutput = true;
  echo $doc->saveXML();
}
die;


/*
Take a look at gettoken() at http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/21/5/6
It breaks the stream into much simpler pieces.
In the next step the parser would "combine" or structure the simple tokens into more complex things.
This function does both....
@return array(id, array(parameter)
*/
function getstruct($fp) {
  if ( feof($fp) ) {
    return false;
  }
  // shortcut: all we care about "happens" on one line
  // so let php read one line in a single step and then do the pattern matching
  $line = trim(fgets($fp));

  // this matches **key** and **header - subheader**
  if ( preg_match('#^\*\*([^-]+)(?:-(.*))?\*\*$#', $line, $m) ) {
    // only for **header - subheader** $m[2] is set.
    if ( isset($m[2]) ) {
      return array(TYPE_HEADER, array(trim($m[1]), trim($m[2])));
    }
    else {
      return array(TYPE_KEY, array($m[1]));
    }
  }
  // this matches _____________ and means "new item"
  else if ( preg_match('#^_+$#', $line, $m) ) {
    return array(TYPE_DELIMETER, array());
  }
  // any other non-empty line is a single value
  else if ( preg_match('#\S#', $line) ) {
    // you might want to filter the 1),2),3) part out here
    // could also be two diffrent token types
    return array(TYPE_VALUE, array($line));
  }
  else {
    // skip empty lines, would be nicer with tail-recursion...
    return getstruct($fp);
  }
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FOODS>
  <FOOD type="TYPE A">
    <PRODUCT>1) Mi Pueblito Queso Fresco Authentic Mexican Style Fresh Cheese;</PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>2) La Fe String Cheese</PRODUCT>
    <CODE>Sell by date going back to February 1, 2009</CODE>
    <MANUFACTURER>Quesos Mi Pueblito, LLC, Passaic, NJ.</MANUFACTURER>
    <VOLUME OF UNITS>11,000 boxes</VOLUME OF UNITS>
    <DISTRIBUTION>NJ, NY, DE, MD, CT, VA</DISTRIBUTION>
  </FOOD>
  <FOOD type="TYPE A">
    <PRODUCT>1) Peanut Brittle No Sugar Added;</PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>2) Peanut Brittle Small Grind;</PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>3) Homestyle Peanut Brittle Nuggets/Coconut Oil Coating</PRODUCT>
    <CODE>1) Lots 7109 - 8350 inclusive;</CODE>
    <CODE>2) Lots 8198 - 8330 inclusive;</CODE>
    <CODE>3) Lots 7075 - 9012 inclusive;</CODE>
    <CODE>4) Lots 7100 - 8057 inclusive;</CODE>
    <CODE>5) Lots 7152 - 8364 inclusive</CODE>
    <MANUFACTURER>Star Kay White, Inc., Congers, NY.</MANUFACTURER>
    <VOLUME OF UNITS>5,749 units</VOLUME OF UNITS>
    <DISTRIBUTION>NY, NJ, MA, PA, OH, FL, TX, UT, CA, IA, NV, MO and IN</DISTRIBUTION>
  </FOOD>
  <FOOD type="TYPE B">
    <PRODUCT>Cool River Bebidas Naturales - West Indian Cherry Fruit Acerola 16% Juice;</PRODUCT>
    <CODE>990-10/2 10/5</CODE>
    <MANUFACTURER>San Mar Manufacturing Corp., Catano, PR.</MANUFACTURER>
    <VOLUME OF UNITS>384</VOLUME OF UNITS>
    <DISTRIBUTION>PR</DISTRIBUTION>
  </FOOD>
</FOODS>
```

Unfortunately the status of the php module for [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) currently is "[Runtime is in alpha status.](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets)" but it might be worth a try anyway...

Comment: This is a great example - I can take it from here. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: BTW, did I miss something? Where did you reference ANTLR in your code?

Comment: oh no no, I didn't use ANTLR for the example. I just urge you to take a look at the project even though php is not a viable target platform yet.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/21/5/6

This tells you how to parse a text file into tokens using PHP. Once parsed you can place it into anything you want.

You need to search for specific tokens in the file based on your criteria:

for example:
**PRODUCT**

This gives you the XML Tag

Then 1) can have special meaning

1) Peanut Brittle...

This tells you what to put in the XML tag.

I do not know if this is the most efficient way to accomplish your task but it is the way a compiler would parse a file and has the potential to make very accurate.

Comment: Thanks, but this is for the actual mechanics of "parsing" - the ciritical peice missing here is how to parse a text file (or string) with different levels of heirarchy and save it into a xml file.

Comment: You parse it then you get every piece. You then assign levels of hierarchy base upon specifics in the token. This is how a compiler works. It looks like you could use the numbers 1) ... to assign levels for the XML.

Comment: Can you modify your answer to show how to send different levels of heirarchy into an xml output?

Comment: My point was that this process of "load line, **multiple** nested conditions, separate function call to add a node to xml file, loop" is feasible, but is this the **best** or most *efficient* way to do this, vs. running a handful of regex expression to search and replace, and at least get a rough cut of an xml string finished?

Comment: Thanks Todd for answering. I still am looking for a more "minimalistic" solution based on Regex (see the changed title), but I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Regex or PHP use the XSLT 2.0 unparsed-text() function to read the file (see http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200508/msg00085.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another Hint for an XSLT 1.0 Solution is here: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/808619-read-plain-file-xslt-1-0-a

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this for future projects - thanks.